# How to pass the selected row ID to Model in yiiwheels.widgets.grid.WhGridView

Tags: php, yii

using this `bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn` try create a button column. How to set ID value to this?

we tried `'id' => '$data->Id'`, like below which didn't work.

```
    array(        
    'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbButtonColumn',
    'template' => '{linkPatient} {toggleVisit} {update} {delete}',
    'buttons' => array(
    'linkPatient' => array(                                                
    'label' => 'Link Patient',
    'icon' => 'icon-user', 
    'id' => '$data->Id',
    'options' => array('data-toggle' =>'modal',
     'data-target' => '#myModal',                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
      ),                                                
      ),
```

- Then how to pass this Id value to the modal dialogBox.
- How to change button column icon onClick like toogle and execute some other function,.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `'options'=>array()` to set id. Or use htmlOptions [Look here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CButtonColumn#htmlOptions-detail)